# validar datos y luego abrir modal

Tags: javascript, validación, modal

Tengo un formulario de ecomerce y la validación de datos ya esta hecha, pero quiero que valide esos datos y después me ponga el modal para continuar la compra.
Al pulsar el botón me valida los datos pero aunque estén incompletos me abre el modal, dejo el código de la validación, del botón y del form

FORM

```
<form action="#" method="get" class="row mt-4 needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="col">
              <h1 class="mb-3">Registro</h1>
              <hr class="my-4">
              <div class="row g-3">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label for="nombre" class="form-label ">Calle</label>
                  <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="street">
                  <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Campo Valido!
                  </div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Ingresa un nombre de calle valido!
                  </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label for="apellido" class="form-label">Número de puerta</label>
                  <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="door-number">
                  <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Campo Valido!
                  </div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Ingresa un número de puerta valido!
                  </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-12">
                  <label for="email" class="form-label">Esquina</label>
                  <input required type="email" class="form-control" id="corner">
                  <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Campo Valido!
                  </div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Ingresa una esquina valida!
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="registrar" >Verificar dirección</button>
    
    
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

VALIDACION JAVASCRIPT para el form en la que valido que los datos se llenen correctamente

```
(() => {
    'use strict'
  
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
  
    
    Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
      form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
          
          
        }
  
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false) 
    })
})()
```

BOTON QUE ABRE EL MODAL Y HACE LA VERIFICACION este es el que deberia hacer la verificacion y luego si esta correcta abrir el modal

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="registrar" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalPayment" >Verificar dirección</button>
```

Comment: El botón hace lo que le pides, que son ambas cosas.  Si lo que quieres es controlar el modal despues de una accion que se ejecuta dentro del submit entonces debes poner alli el código para abrir el modal y no en el botón.  En [este enlace](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#passing-options) te muestran como se puede hacer desde javascript con el método **show** del modal.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias era re simple y me estaba complicando la vida

Comment: bien, me alegro que ya lo tengas arreglado :-)  Saludos!   (si acaso redacta tu la respuesta de lo que has hecho para que la comunidad lo sepa y en 48 horas podras aceptartela tu mismo)